# Conditional Group By and Select using Linq (NHibernate)

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have that query :

```
var group = query.GroupBy(x => new
{
   ...
   TestName =  isSelected ? x.ClassA.Name : "" 
});

var select = group.Select(y => new MyResultDTO()
{
   ...
   TestName = isSelected ? y.First().ClassA.Name : ""  
});
```

That is not woriking ... I got an error :

**Column 'tblClassA.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

But if I change my groupBy to only (take of condicional clause):

```
TestName = x.ClassA.Name
```

It works fine...
Any idea how can I do that condicional GroupBy/Select ?

I´m using NHibernate 3.3.1

Paul

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I don't think you need a `GroupBy` here.

Comment: Its just a small part of my code... I´m grouping my result with several other Attributes, and some of than are optional (checkbox in UI)

Comment: The select list in SQL can only contain columns present in the group by clause (outside aggregates). This is simply because the group by makes it impossible to know with value to use in the returned row for columns not aggregated or in the group by. Now, if you have a conditional expression in the group by so that it will only sometimes use the value of the column, it follows that you cannot use that column directly in the select list. I think it might work if you use the exact same expression also in the select list. On the other hand, it's not entirely clear what your end goal is.

Comment: Thanks... Which expression Oskar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of what you want to achieve, but have you tried writing ?

```
var select = group.Select(y => new MyResultDTO()
{
   ...
   TestName = y.Key.TestName  
});
```

Also, you may try something like this for your group :

```
var group = query.Where(isSel=>isSel.isSelected).GroupBy(x => new
{
   ...
   TestName =  x.ClassA.Name 
})
.Union(query.Where(isSel=>!isSel.isSelected).GroupBy(x => new
{
   ...
   TestName = "" 
});
```

Hope this will help